# Change Google Map Zoom Speed on Zoom Slider

Tags: google-maps, zooming

I'm trying to change the google map zoom slider (zoomControl)'s "+/-" button's zoom speed.
I'm using google.maps.map with the default zoomControl.
Currently, I'm thinking of using an event listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(
zoomControl_plus_button,
'click',
function() {
  // map is a google.maps.map.
  map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 2);
});
```

but I don't know how to get the zoomControl_plus_button.

Is there a way to get that button, or a different way to set the zoomControl's zoom speed?